# Need insights in constructing query for below scenario in snowflake

Tags: sql, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1TJ.png)

Hello ,

Need help in constructing sql query for the above scenario. The above image is how input data comes in .

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nliQ4.png)

As you can see in the above expected output on how status field and owner field (audit values) are anchored to each other.

I expected the source data to stamp timestamp for every change but that didnot happen

I have restriction in snowflake to write pl/sql code for this. Trying to achieve thru sql only.

Environment DB : Snowflake.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. You need to show source tables and data, the result you want to achieve based on that data, the SQL you’ve managed to write and an explanation of what the issue is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.